# Proving any propositional formula can be written a certain way

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[image]

How do I start with this? I know that there are $2^4$ different possible truth tables for $P$ but i'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Just write them out, all 16 of them.  Some are trivial, some requires a little more thoughts.

Comment: Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Note that there is a certain symmetry to this question, which should help you reduce the number of cases a lot.

Comment: Can you explain? i'm trying to prove the general case, not the example!

Comment: What general case?  It only works for formula in 2 variables, not $n$ variables.

Comment: I meant the general case for 2 variables, not the example given in the question. I don't see the symmetry that you're alluding to, can you give me a hint?

Comment: @user140161 Have you written those 16 truth tables?

Comment: Yes I have written them!

Comment: How many of those 16 functions can you write as $A\Box B$?

Comment: Supposedly all of them, however how I don't know how to go in reverse and to find A and B  and the operator between them

Comment: That's something that must be covered in your textbook, but in principle, you don't need to.  Write all expressions of the form $A \Box B$, write their truth tables, and verify that you got all 16 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the equivalence of formulae
$$\def\lequiv{\Leftrightarrow}
\begin{align*}
\lnot(A\lor B)&\sim(\lnot A)\land(\lnot B)\\
\lnot(A\land B)&\sim(\lnot A)\lor(\lnot B)\\
\lnot(A\lequiv B)&\sim(\lnot A)\lequiv B\\
(\lnot\lnot A)\square B&\sim A\square B\\
A\square\lnot\lnot B&\sim A\square B\\
\end{align*}
$$
so for every $P$ it suffices to show one of $P,\lnot P$ is equivalent to $A\square B$.

Now count how many times $P$ is true (for brevity I'll say "$X$ is true" instead of "a $\{\bot,\top\}$-valuation $v$ such that $v(X)=\top$"):

- If $P$ is never true, then $P\sim(p\lequiv\lnot p)$.  By duality we get $P$ always true.
- If $P$ is true only in one case then $P$ is obviously equivalent to $A\land B$ where we can read $A,B$ from the truth table.  Dually this gives $P$ true in all-but-one case.
- All that remains is when $P$ is true in two cases (and false in the other two).  WLOG suppose $P$ is true when both $p,q$ are.  There is another case of $(p,q)$ where $P$ is true, i.e., one of $(\bot,\bot),(\bot,\top),(\top,\bot)$.  It isn't hard to write down an equivalent $A\square B$ in each of these cases.  For example, for $(\top,\bot)$, we have $P$ is true if (and only if) $p$ is, so we can use $p\land p$.